# Unity assembly files missing from "Temp/bin/Debug"

Tags: unity, c#, macos, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use VS Code on a Mac with Unity and C#. When I try to open a Unity project in VS Code, it can't load *Assembly*.dll* files from few locations which are defined by default in *.csproj* files; *"Temp\bin\Debug\"*.

When I check the *Temp\bin\Debug* paths, while Unity is running, they are empty; they doe not contain the assembly files, where I assume they should. The files are in *"Library/ScriptAssemblies"*. Moving them is not an option, because I would have to do that manually every time I change *sth.* in any script file. Changing the path in the *.csproj* files is also not a good idea, because those files get rewritten every time you open a project in Unity.

---

This issue causes lot of problems in the editor:

> [WARNING:OmniSharp#MSBuild] Unable to resolve assembly '/[...]/Temp/bin/Debug/Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll'
>   [INFORMATION:OmniSharp#MSBuild] Update project: Assembly-CSharp-Editor-firstpass
>   [WARNING:OmniSharp#MSBuild] Unable to resolve assembly '/[...]/Temp/bin/Debug/Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll'
>   [INFORMATION:OmniSharp#MSBuild] Update project: Assembly-CSharp-Editor
>   [WARNING:OmniSharp#MSBuild] Unable to resolve assembly '/[...]/Temp/bin/Debug/Assembly-CSharp-Editor-firstpass.dll'
>   [WARNING:OmniSharp#MSBuild] Unable to resolve assembly '/[...]/Temp/bin/Debug/Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll'

All type references coming from my custom scripts and the `UnityEngine` namespace are missing, and highlighted as errors:

[image: <code>UnityEngine</code> and <code>GameObhect</code> reports an error: "The type or namespace could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [netcoreapp1.1]"]

However, intellisense seems to be working fine for `UnityEngine` types:
[image: Intellisense recognises the methods in <code>MonoBehaviour</code>.]

---

I tried to reinstall MonoDevelop it a few times, including a brew and downloadable package. MonoDevelop seems to be installed properly:

> `$ mono --version`
>    `Mono JIT compiler version 4.6.2 (mono-4.6.0-branch/ac9e222 Wed Dec 14 17:02:09 EST 2016)`
>    `Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com`
>     `TLS:           normal`
>     `SIGSEGV:       altstack`
>     `Notification:  kqueue`
>     `Architecture:  x86`
>     `Disabled:      none`
>     `Misc:          softdebug`
>     `LLVM:          yes(3.6.0svn-mono-master/8b1520c)`
>     `GC:            sgen`

.NET works as well:

> `$ dotnet --version`
>   `1.0.0-preview2-1-003177`

---

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution came quicker than i expected, after some experimentations with creating new project and running it in VS Code (which was a successfull try) I've decided to remove whole `.vscode` directory from project dir and it worked.

Thx guys ;)

Comment: This also solved the problem for me... Not sure what went wrong.